# Wordpress theme alter order of stylesheets

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've followed these two links of a `"tutorial"` to set up a WP page with the use of git and composer.

1. https://deliciousbrains.com/storing-wordpress-in-git/
2. https://deliciousbrains.com/using-composer-manage-wordpress-themes-plugins/

My question: 
By looking at the network tab of the developer tools on chrome I see that the bootstrap stylesheet gets called as last one, and so its overwrite the theme styles and my child-theme styles. 
But I want the following order:

**first:** bootstrap styles, second parent-theme styles, and third `child-theme` styles.

How do I accomplish that goal without touching the parent-theme directly?

Or do I get something wrong and this order, as it is now is intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dependency parameter of `wp_enequeue_style` function : Filenames are used as example, please change according to your need.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts' );
/**  Enqueue scripts and styles.  **/
function mytheme_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootsrap-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css','', 'v1' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css',['bootsrap-styles',''], 'v1' );

}
```

Comment: Thank you, i was not aware that i could alter the order in my child-theme functions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through your theme's functions.php

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_style('mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.css' );
}, 99);
```

Wordpress will place the stated .css file in your header and giving a 99 priority, which means it will add it later than the rest. You can do this for each of the desired .css files and maintain your own preferred order.